# Smoothed 2D histogram using matplotlib and imshow

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I try to do a 2D histogram plot and to obtain a "smooth" picture by a sort of interpolation. Thus I do the following combining `plt.hist2d` and `plt.imshow`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("parametre_optMC.dat", skiprows=50, usecols=(1,2))

h, x, y, p = plt.hist2d(data[:,0], data[:,1], bins = 20)
plt.imshow(h, origin = "lower", interpolation = "gaussian")
plt.savefig("test.pdf")
```

As you can see on the picture below, the two plots are superimposed and that is the problem for which I need some help

[image]

Adding clf works but I lose axes dimenions :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("parametre_optMC.dat", skiprows=50, usecols=(1,2))

h, x, y, p = plt.hist2d(data[:,0], data[:,1], bins = 20)
plt.clf()
plt.imshow(h, origin = "lower", interpolation = "gaussian")
plt.savefig("test.pdf")
```

[image]

Comment: You might still have data from a previous plot in your figure. If you do `plt.clf()` and `plt.close()` it will be cleared.

Comment: Ok, it works but I lose axes dimensions. I edit the post.

Comment: Do you only want to see the smoothed picture? I am not sure what the question is.

Comment: Yes, I only want the smoothed one. But as you can see axes scale are not the same before and after `imshow`.

Comment: Try looking at answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18696122/1461850

Answer (score 17):

Perhaps it would be better to plot a kernel density estimate?

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], [(1, .6), (.6, 1)], 100)
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
sns.kdeplot(data, shade=True, ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: Not working anymore (seaborn 0.11.2), fails with error "If using all scalar values, you must pass an index". Apparently seaborn needs new type of structure for data.

Comment: Made it work again with
```
data = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], [(1, .6), (.6, 1)], 100)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['X','Y'])
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
sns.kdeplot(data = df, shade=True, ax=ax, x='X', y='Y')
```

Comment: `shade=True` is now replaced by `fill=True`

Answer (score 1):

To your first question:

You need to clear data from a previous plot, putting the following before you plot should do this:

```
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

To your second question:

To change the axis values I'd suggest the `extent` parameter (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18696354/1461850)).

e.g. something like:

```
plt.imshow(h, origin = "lower", interpolation = "gaussian",extent=[-100,100,-75,75])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the 'extent' parameter to you imshow command. imshow accepts a grid of arbitrary values but does not know the dimensions.