# Matplotlib: personalize imshow axis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the results of a `(H,ranges) = numpy.histogram2d()` computation and I'm trying to plot it.

Given `H` I can easily put it into `plt.imshow(H)` to get the corresponding image. (see http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow )

My problem is that the axis of the produced image are the "cell counting" of `H` and are completely unrelated to the values of `ranges.`

I know I can use the keyword `extent` (as pointed in: [Change values on matplotlib imshow() graph axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696122/change-values-on-matplotlib-imshow-graph-axis) ). But this solution does not work for me: my values on `range` are not growing linearly (actually they are going exponentially)

**My question is:** How can I put the value of `range` in `plt.imshow()`? Or at least, or can I manually set the label values of the `plt.imshow` resulting object?

Editing the `extent` is not a good solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just change the tick labels to something more appropriate for your data.

For example, here we'll set every 5th pixel to an exponential function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = np.random.rand(21,21)

fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax1.imshow(im)
ax2.imshow(im)

# Where we want the ticks, in pixel locations
ticks = np.linspace(0,20,5)
# What those pixel locations correspond to in data coordinates.
# Also set the float format here
ticklabels = ["{:6.2f}".format(i) for i in np.exp(ticks/5)]

ax2.set_xticks(ticks)
ax2.set_xticklabels(ticklabels)
ax2.set_yticks(ticks)
ax2.set_yticklabels(ticklabels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: super! I implemented it in few minutes and did exactly the job!

Comment: This is dangerous as you have de-coupled the tick labels from the data values.

Answer (score 8):

Expanding a bit on @thomas answer

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mi

im = np.random.rand(20, 20)

ticks = np.exp(np.linspace(0, 10, 20))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.pcolor(ticks, ticks, im, cmap='viridis')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')

ax.set_xlim([1, np.exp(10)])
ax.set_ylim([1, np.exp(10)])
```

[image: example result]

By letting mpl take care of the non-linear mapping you can now accurately over-plot other artists.  There is a performance hit for this (as `pcolor` is more expensive to draw than `AxesImage`), but getting accurate ticks is worth it.

Answer (score 5):

`imshow` is for displaying images, so it does not support x and y bins. 
You could either use `pcolor` instead,

```
H,xedges,yedges = np.histogram2d()
plt.pcolor(xedges,yedges,H)
```

or use `plt.hist2d` which directly plots your histogram.