# How can I cut the axis for this image and center the axis?

Tags: python, anaconda

I start to learn about segmentation, and I want to start with my picture, but when I attach my image, the axis are not where I want. Also, I try with a filter but it doesn't work for my picture.

this is the picture the code create:

[image]

```
import scipy.ndimage
from PIL import Image
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter


im= Image.open('0.tiff')
#im.show()
plt.imshow(im)
im = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(im, sigma=1)
```

Comment: concerning the plot, you should look for how to configure `Imshow`, e.g. [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) or [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696122/change-values-on-matplotlib-imshow-graph-axis).